# How do initiate load of content for ChildRowContent in MudBlazor table

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I've seen the Blazor example of having a table with related data [here](https://mudblazor.com/components/table#table-with-related-data).  It works on the principal that the initial table data already contains the data that will be shown in the ChildRowContent.

What my scenario calls for is for the content to be loaded from a separate http call at run-time when the user expands the main table row.

Any guidance as to how that can be achieved would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to load all the detail data with the main ones, just leave in you main class a list field empty, that you will fill with your details once the user expande the row.

Here you are a working example based on your snippet. Starting from this you can add your API calls and should add a loader. Hope it can help.

```cs
<MudTable Items="@People" Hover="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm">
    <ColGroup>
        <col style="width:300px;" />
        <col style="width:100px;" />
        <col />
        <col style="width:100px;" />
    </ColGroup>
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh></MudTh>
        <MudTh>Nr</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Age</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd><MudButton Variant="Variant.Outlined" Size="Size.Small" OnClick="@(() => ShowBtnPress(context.Number))">@((context.ShowDetails == true)? "Hide" : "Show") Address Details</MudButton></MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@context.Number</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Age">@context.Age</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
    <ChildRowContent>
        @if (context.ShowDetails)
        {
            <MudTr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <MudCard Elevation="0">
                    <MudCardHeader>
                    <CardHeaderContent>
                    <MudText Typo="Typo.body1">Address Details for <strong>@context.Name</strong></MudText>
                    </CardHeaderContent>
                    </MudCardHeader>
                    <MudCardContent Class="pa-0">
                    <MudTable Items="@context.Addresses" Context="AddressContext" Hover="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm" Elevation="0">
                    <ColGroup>
                        <col />
                        <col />
                        <col style="width:200px;" />
                    </ColGroup>
                    <HeaderContent>
                        <MudTh>Address Line 1</MudTh>
                        <MudTh>Address Line 2</MudTh>
                        <MudTh>Postal Code</MudTh>
                    </HeaderContent>
                    <RowTemplate>
                        <MudTd DataLabel="Address Line 1">@AddressContext.Address_Line_1</MudTd>
                        <MudTd DataLabel="Address Line 2">@AddressContext.Address_Line_2</MudTd>
                        <MudTd DataLabel="Postal Code">@AddressContext.Postal_Code</MudTd>
                    </RowTemplate>
                    </MudTable>
                    </MudCardContent>
                    </MudCard>
                </td>
            </MudTr>
        }
    </ChildRowContent>
</MudTable>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        FillPeople();
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string Address_Line_1 { get; set; }
        public string Address_Line_2 { get; set; }
        public int Postal_Code { get; set; }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public bool ShowDetails { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    }
    private void FillPeople()
    {
        IList<Person> people = new List<Person>();

        people.Add(new Person
        {
            ShowDetails = false,
            Number = 1,
            Name = "Harry Potter",
            Age = 11
        });

        people.Add(new Person
        {
            ShowDetails = false,
            Number = 2,
            Name = "Ash Ketchum",
            Age = 18
        });

        people.Add(new Person
        {
            ShowDetails = false,
            Number = 3,
            Name = "Frodo Baggins",
            Age = 24
        });
        
        People = people;
    }
    private async Task FillAddresses(int nr)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); //Example time waiting for API call
        Person tmpPerson = People.First(f => f.Number == nr);
        IList<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();
        switch(nr) 
        {
            case 1:
                addresses.Add(new Address { Address_Line_1 = "4 Privet Drive", Address_Line_2 = "Little Whinging", Postal_Code = 111 });
                addresses.Add(new Address { Address_Line_1 = "12 Grimmauld Place", Address_Line_2 = "The Burrow", Postal_Code = 333 });     
                break;
            case 2:
                addresses.Add(new Address { Address_Line_1 = "123 Pikachu Lane", Address_Line_2 = "Pallet Town", Postal_Code = 777 });
                addresses.Add(new Address { Address_Line_1 = "456 Mew Street", Address_Line_2 = "Pallet Town", Postal_Code = 999 });
                break;
            case 3:
                addresses.Add(new Address { Address_Line_1 = "123 Shire Lane", Address_Line_2 = "Bag End", Postal_Code = 223 });
                addresses.Add(new Address { Address_Line_1 = "456 Shire Street", Address_Line_2 = "Bag End", Postal_Code = 445 });
                addresses.Add(new Address { Address_Line_1 = "789 Shire Avenue", Address_Line_2 = "Bag End", Postal_Code = 667 });
                break;
        }

        tmpPerson.Addresses = addresses;
    }
    private static IEnumerable<Person> People { get; set; }

    private async Task ShowBtnPress(int nr)
    {
        Person tmpPerson = People.First(f => f.Number == nr);
        tmpPerson.ShowDetails = !tmpPerson.ShowDetails;
        await FillAddresses(nr);    //replace with API call
    }
}
```

Try it here:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QEwRORPfdoBIAbwq